# Recursive Descent Parser and Nested Parentheses

Tags: parsing, grammar, recursive-descent

I'm new to the area of grammars and parsing.

I'm trying to write a recursive descent parser that evaluates strings like this:

((3 == 5 AND 4 == 5) OR (6 == 6 ))

Everything works fine for me until I start to deal with nested parentheses.  Essentially I find that I'm reaching the end of my target string too early.

I think the problem is due to the fact when I encounter a token like the "6" or the second-to-last parenthesis, I evaluate it and then move to the next token.  I'd remove the code for advancing to the next token, but then I'm not sure how I move forward.

My grammar, such as it is, looks like this (the "=>" signs are my own notation for the "translation" of a rule):

Test: If CompoundSentence Then CompoundSentence | CompoundSentence

CompoundSentence :   ( CompoundSentence ) PCSopt |CompoundSentence Conjunction Sentence |

Sentence =>

CompoundSentence = ( CompoundSentence ) PCSopt  | Sentence CSOpt

PCSOpt = ParenConjunction CompoundSentence PCSOpt| Epsilon

CSOpt = Conjunction Sentence CSOpt| Epsilon

ParenConjunction:  And|Or

Conjunction: And|Or

Sentence : Subject Verb Prefix

Subject:  Subject Infix Value | Value   =>

Subject = Value SubjectOpt

SubjectOpt = Infix Value SubjectOpt | Epsilon

Verb: ==|!=|>|<

Predicate:  Predicate Infix Value | Value   =>

Predicate= Value PredicateOpt

PredicateOpt = Infix Value PredicateOpt | Epsilon

Infix:  +, -, *, /

My code for a compound sentence is as follows:

```
    private string CompoundSentence(IEnumerator<Token> ts)
    {
        //  CompoundSentence = ( CompoundSentence ) PCSopt  | Sentence CSOpt

        string sReturnValue = "";

        switch(ts.Current.Category) {

            case "OPENPAREN":
            {
                     //Skip past the open parenthesis
                ts.MoveNext();

                string sCSValue = CompoundSentence(ts);

                if(ts.Current.Category != "CLOSEPAREN") {

                    sReturnValue = "Missing parenthesis at " + ts.Current.OriginalString;
                    return sError;
                }
                else {

                        //Skip past the close parenthesis
                    ts.MoveNext();  
                }

                sReturnValue = PCSOpt(sCSValue, ts);

                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                string sSentenceVal = Sentence(ts);

                    //sSentenceVal is the truth value -- "TRUE" or "FALSE"
                    //of the initial Sentence component
                    //CSOpt will use that value, along with the particular conjunction
                    //and the value of the current token, 
                    //to generate a new truth value.
                sReturnValue = CSOpt(sSentenceVal, ts);

                break;
            }
        }

        return sReturnValue;
    }
```

As I say, I'm new to this area, so I'm probably not understanding something quite fundamental.

If anyone could steer me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For expressions, a hand-coded recursive descent parser is a pretty easy thing to code.

See my [SO answer for how to write recursive descent parsers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769)

Once you have the structure of the parser, it is pretty easy to evaluate an expression as-you-parse.

Answer (score 0):

The basic convention to follow for parsing is:

1. At the start of a rule, the current token should be the first token that the rule covers.
2. A rule should consume all of the tokens it covers.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was incredibly subtle, but it turns out to have been quite simple: my scanner wasn't catching the second (and probably higher) close parentheses.  Ouch.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Ira, I'll accept your answer for the detailed help it provides on RDP's.